# Flutter -desktop :How can I control the initial offset of an item at the start of dragging in reorderable listview

Tags: flutter, offset, flutter-reorderable-listview

I'm currently using reorderable listview in flutter desktop and when I long press on an item, it jump to an offset that I find too far from it's previous original one, how can I controll how far the item will go away from it's original position at the start of dragging in reorderable listview in flutter desktop?